# Session stored data not working in modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have E-commerce kind of website. I want to know information stored in session can be retrieved insided ModalPopupExtender or not after postback. I tried to store some details in session & after postback I get that info from session but it's not retrieving. I tried to debug it & I see the values not getting stored in session. Is I'm doing it right by calling session value on pageLoad?

```
Private Sub orderButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles orderButton.Click
        Session("patientName") = patientName.Text
        Session("address1") = address1.Text

        If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("chkusername") Is Nothing Then
            MPlogin.Show()
        Else  
            condition code executes
        End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub Online_Medicines_order_online_order_by_prescription_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Session("patientName") Is Nothing Then
            patientName.Text = ""
        Else
            patientName.Text = Session("patientName").ToString
        End If

        If Session("address1") Is Nothing Then
            address1.Text = ""
        Else
            address1.Text = Session("address1").ToString
        End If
End Sub
```